# How does "Rotation Locker" work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I just installed the app Rotation Locker a moment ago. It is a simple app but it work so great. It can force all other apps run in landscape or portrait mode.
I am struggling to figure out how it can do this. Can anybody tell me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Piecing together data from other posts I was able how to work this out for an app I was writing that needs to do exactly this. ([Force Dock Rotation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.chrispaton.forcedockrotation) if you're interested).

My solution involves creating a window and inserting it at the top of the view hierarchy so that you can get first shout of the orientation before another app tries to set it...

```
orientationChanger = new LinearLayout(this);
// Using TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY is crucial to make your window appear on top
// You'll need the permission android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
WindowManager.LayoutParams orientationLayout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
// Use whatever constant you need for your desired rotation
orientationLayout.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR;

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(orientationChanger, orientationLayout);
orientationChanger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Credit to this answer for the inspiration: [How can I globally force screen orientation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587085/how-can-i-globally-force-screen-orientation-in-android/14654302#14654302)

Comment: The code that you have shared is not working for me. I want to make default orientation of device to be portrait on some condition. When i received that event i had written your code , but its not changing orientation to Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can just hold the SEARCH button or some other button.

This is the way it works on HTC Desire

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i think you dont understand what i asked. What i really want to know is that how can i do to create a similar app like that.